# Browser Evaluation Context

Tags: javascript

How can I run code using a single browser evaluation context.

On a Firefox browser "Console" I can select "Top" from the bottom right corner, this allows me to execute 'console.log' however I do not have access to the buttons on the webpage, in order to have access to the button elements I need to select 1 level down from 'Top' on the 'Select evaluation context' (similar to using inspector tool and clicking the button to set focus on that element) however I can no longer use console.log (undefined) when selecting a level lower on 'Select evaluation'.

Summary:

Select evaluation: Top = can use console.log but not have access to webpage buttons.

Select evaluation: Webpage (Level lower than Top) = can access buttons but not console.log.

```
//TOP
checkFunc();
var i = 2;
function checkFunc(){
    if (i == 1){
        console.log("T-1");
    }else{
        console.log("T-2");
    }
}

//LOW LEVEL
var label = document.getElementsByClassName("font-family-title label")[0].innerText;
label;
```

The 2 above codes cannot both work from the same 'Select evaluation context' option.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? I don't use it regularly but I have v91 installed, and it doesn't have anything in "the bottom left corner" of the Console tab. In the top right cornder there's a box where you can select which frame you're working in. Are you working in a document with frames?

Comment: What does *"I can no longer use console.log (undefined)"* mean? I can't imagine what you'd have in a frame that would make `console.log` not work unless there's code there actively making it not work (e.g., `console = undefined;`).

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation context means the page is using iframes.

And what you want to do is select something inside an iframe (a.k.a different context).

You need to select the iframe and then proceed. Since I don't have the context and HTML of the page I'm assuming there is only one iframe in the example below but you can change it as you see fit.

Here is example how you can execute your code inside the iframe:

```js
 const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe"); // change to correctly select your iframe

 const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

console.log(innerDoc.body); // This will print everything in the iframe

// Then you can select your own label
const label = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("font-family-title label")[0].innerText;
```

Note: ALL of the code above should be executed in the TOP context.

This way you can get everything you need from the iframe and not needing to change the context